# Lightning Issues on Notes and Attachments added to a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, attachment

I have a visualforce page on a custom object. On save it is redirected to the notes and attachments page. We are now moving to lightning and notes and attachments feature is available. How do I redirect my page to Files in lightning ?

Comment: The feature is not available*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the navigateToSObject method in your lightning component's controller.

Example from the handleClick js method:

```
({

handleClick : function (component, event, helper) {
    var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": "069580000000IIJAA2",
      "slideDevName": "detail"
    });
    navEvt.fire();
}
```

})